# Android Studio : Gradle Executin Failed with dexDebug Error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, dex

I have faced the following dexDebug error. i cannot fix this.

Error:Execution failed for task ':sampleApplication:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Note: i even checked my dependencies in my build.gradle. there is no duplicate values.

Comment: Usually you got a little bit more information from the build logs. Can you add this to your ticket?

Comment: use gradlew assemble --info to get more info

Comment: While adding crashlytics with my application, i just got this kind of error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> defaultConfig {
>       multiDexEnabled true }

Comment: Not all problems in building time are related to multiDex.

Comment: Yep.. I agree with you.. I just got the same error while adding plugins. I have rectified through above ..